# Copy-paste multiple values to their placeholders notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++

Suppose markup (many lines with same structure)

```
<a href="">xxx</a>
<a href="">yyy</a>
<a href="">zzz</a>
```

What is the best way to achive this? (copy-paste into href="")

```
<a href="xxx">xxx</a>
<a href="yyy">yyy</a>
<a href="zzz">zzz</a>
```

My thoughts: execute JS then copy html from browser, but seems a bit cumbersome. Any notepad++ solution?

```
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following replacement in regex mode:

```
Find:    <a href="">(.*?)</a>
Replace: <a href="$1">$1</a>
```

Here is a working regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iKSiqy/1).

Comment: seems exactly what I needed. for some reason I didn't manage to google it...